# Conceptually, why does an electric field not require a charge flowing through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields

My son has been asking me a lot about electromagnetism and so I got to read up on it.One of the interesting and hard to grasp (for me at least) concepts is that an electric field will exist even when there is no current flowing.

> - How exactly does this occur?
> - What difference between an electric field with a charge flowing through it and one without? Does the charge flowing through an electric field alter the electric field?
> - What happens to the charged particle as it enters the field? What does it experience as it progresses through the field?

Comment: You need moving charges to produce *magnetic fields* and not *electric fields*. Exactly where did you read this concept?

Comment: Perhaps if this is the reason, the arrows sometimes drawn to the electric field don't indicate any necessary speed of charges. They're the direction of the electric field itself. The arrows are there even - and especially - if the electrically charged source is at rest. These arrows indicate where an initially static charge wants to accelerate if you place it in the electric field - the direction of the force (and acceleration); this answers the last question.

Comment: The electric fields are primarily created by static electric charges. Moving charges - like in the electromagnet (coil) - produce magnetic fields which are independent of the electric fields at each point of space. Electromagnetism - effects of the fields on particles and vice versa - is a fundamental part of the equations of physics that can't really be reduced to anything "simpler", see e.g. this monologue by Feynman about the very point http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. an $E$ field is simply a region in which an $E$ charge experiences a force. therefore when two charges are sufficiently close by, they experience a mutual force. every charge is surrounded by its own $E$ field, in the same way every magnet is surrounded by its own magnetic field (or $B$ field) and every massive particle is surrounded by its own gravitational field. none of these need to be moving to set up a field.
2. when two charges interact they necessarily alter the shape of the $E$ field, especially between them. however the amount of alteration depends on the magnitude of the charge involved. therefore a negligible third charge placed in between the first two charges will experience a force in a straight line connecting them. but a third charge of equal magnitude will bend the $E$ field.
3. a charge entering an $E$ field experiences a force known as the Coulomb force. since charges have mass, the observation is that the charge accelerates along the $E$ field line, however that line may be shaped as per (2).
4. a moving charge (i.e. current) generates a $B$ field around that charge

Answer (score -1):

The electric field is a modification of space properties created by the presence of any distribution of charge. Its existence does not require any moving things.